# Inequality in natural numbers

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Let *v* and *b* be natural numbers satisfying the condition: $1 \le v \lt \frac{b}{2}$. Prove that
$$\frac{v(b-v)}{v+1} \ge \frac{b-1}{2}$$
(remember we need that to be true only for natural $v$ and $b$)

How to prove it?

I started simply by multiplying both sides by $2(v+1)$, which gives a quadratic inequality after simple transformations with regards to $v$:

$$2v^2-(b+1)v+b-1 \le 0$$

$$ \Delta = \left(b-3\right)^2$$

$$ \sqrt{\Delta} = \lvert b - 3 \rvert $$

Let's assume $b \ge 3$ for a moment. Then we have:

$$v_1 = 1$$
$$v_2 = \frac{b-1}{2}$$

and we get the solution:

$$1 \le v \le \frac{b-1}{2}$$

Since *b* is natural, it's the same as:

$$1 \le v \lt \frac{b}{2}$$

which is our condition. Of course, we should also consider what happens when $b \lt 3$.

Anyway, I kind of think there's got to be a simpler way of proving it, not involving quadratic equations etc., just simple transformations making use of the fact that we want the inequality to be true only for natural *v* and *b*. Can someone show me a simpler reasoning leading to a simpler and more elegant proof?

Comment: You've also gone backwards:  you proved $B \Rightarrow A$ when you wanted $A \Rightarrow B$.

Comment: You are right! So, anyway, my "proof" is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your inequality in the form

$$\frac{v(b-v)}{v+1}-\frac{b-1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(v-1)(b-1-2v)}{v+1}$$

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice, that your Problem is solved now!